# Provider automatically gets updated when calling setState

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am new to Flutter and currently working with Providers. I am pulling some static array list from an api and saving it to the Provider. I am letting the user to select from this list and attach to the Item he is creating using the form.

So, Everytime the user tries to create a new Item, he/she should see the static list with the selection set to false.

But, the provider array variable gets automatically updated upon calling setState. Below is the Issue I'm facing..

**main.dart**

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Info1Class>(
          create: (ctx) => Info1Class(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Info2Class>(
          create: (ctx) => Info1Class(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
```

And in my Stateful widget in the build method. I am getting the Provider Details like this.

```
screenArray.clear();
    final t = Provider.of<Info1Class>(context, listen: false).dataArray;
    screenArray.addAll(t);
```

Whenever I call setState to update the elements of screenArray, the provider data gets updated as well.

`setState(() {screenArray[0].selected = true})`

After setState(), if I print the Provider dataArray's first element, it showing as true.

`print(Provider.of<Info1Class>(context, listen: false).dataArray[0].selected)`

**My Dependancies**

`provider: ^4.3.2+4`

Is there a way to avoid the Provider data getting updated and only update the variable in my Stateful Widget ?

Please let me know if I am missing something.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with List data types only, even in provider and getx both, data is change automatically on setState

Answer (score 0):

I tried Getx and Provider both for this problem, it's problem of referencing of object not the Provider or GetX,
I was coping reference of Objects, list or all data. to Solve this problem, I create clone of each object and then use it.

```
  // COMMON
  String? uid;
  String? username;
  String? fullName;
  String? email;
  num? timestamp;
  List<ProfilePhoto>? photos;
  List<String>? skills;
```

I add one object list and other simple String list
Clone class

```
MyUser.clone(MyUser? myUser) {
        uid = myUser?.uid;
        username = myUser?.username;
        fullName = myUser?.fullName;
        userType = myUser?.userType;
        email = myUser?.email;
        timestamp = myUser?.timestamp;
        photos = ProfilePhoto.cloneList(myUser?.photos);
        status = myUser?.status;
        skills = [...(myUser?.skills ?? [])];
       
      }
```

Constructor

```
MyUser({
     this.uid,
     this.username,
     this.fullName,
     this.email,
     this.timestamp,
     this.photos,
     this.skills,)};
```

Photo class

```
class ProfilePhoto {
  String? id;
  String? title;
  String? url;
  File? file;
  bool? isDefault;



  ProfilePhoto({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.url,
    this.file,
    this.isDefault,
  });

  ProfilePhoto.clone(ProfilePhoto profilePhoto) {
    id = profilePhoto.id;
    title = profilePhoto.title;
    url = profilePhoto.url;
    file = profilePhoto.file;
    isDefault = profilePhoto.isDefault;
  }
  static List<ProfilePhoto>? cloneList(List<ProfilePhoto>? items) {
    if (items == null) return [];
    List<ProfilePhoto>? newItems = [];
    for (ProfilePhoto item in items) {
      newItems.add(ProfilePhoto.clone(item));
    }
    return newItems;
  }
}
```

Screen layout

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  final data = _userController.user;
  MyUser? user = MyUser.clone(data);
}

void _onChangeDefault(int index) {
    ProfilePhoto pp = _profilePhotos[index];
    setState(() {
      _profilePhotos.removeAt(index);
      _profilePhotos.insert(0, pp);
    });
  }
```

this may be not a good or optimized solution, but this solve my problem of auto update data in state manager